# Could there be any implementations where the pw is truncated after "space"

Tags: passwords

A good human memorable password could be:

```
My 1st passw%%%%%!!!!!rd
```

But could there be any password storing implementations that cut off the password after the first space, so the password will be only:

```
My
```

**Question**: Did anyone seen such a bad thing?

Comment: In the world of computer science, every bogus behavior is possible!

Comment: I recently saw an example on codereview that [cut passwords off after the first <](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/111901) (because it used `strip_tags` on the password). It's hard for me to imagine something similar when handling passwords (maybe a bad attempt at stripping trailing whitespace, or generally bad input handling), but who knows, everything is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Question: Did anyone seen such a bad thing?

Not exactly this, but worse things. There were versions of Windows95/ME which only verified that much characters from the password as the user entered, i.e. for connecting to a share protected with "secret" it was enough to enter "s". See [MS00-072](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms00-072.aspx).

Also it is not uncommon that passwords get silently cut at 8 characters or similar. And if an implementation removes white-space from beginning and end that might easily go wrong and remove everything after the first white-space.